# regionprops function returns empty structure in Matlab. why?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, cell

I cannot understand this issue. I have saved a stack of 60 binary images in a cell(myCell). When I try to find the centeroid of each binary image, regionprops returns nothing. center is 0x1 struct. Why?

```
X(256,256,60); %stack of images 
myCell=cell(2,60); %creating the cell
for i=1:60
    myCell{1,i}=X(:,:,i);
    center=regionprops(myCell{1,i},'Centroid');
    if (isempty(center))
        continue;
     else
        myCell{2,i}=round(center.Centroid);

    end
end
```

your help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that you have the 0's and 1's flipped in your binary image? If so you could use `~myCell{1,i}` instead

Comment: Maybe in some cases you only have `0s`, thus no centroid?

Comment: `regionprops` would only return an empty struct if your entire image is black (i.e. 0).  Double check your data to see if this is the case.  Debug and actually show the data: `image(X(:,:,i));`

Comment: @Suever Ander Biguri and rayyeng Thank you very much for your help. It is working now, the values were not binary. Thanks again